# How to use "as such" "corresponding" "accordingly"

Tags: adverbs

> If you click ON a dangerous link, a message saying "This link is
>   dangerous!" will be displayed.

I am trying to describe the meaning of the above sentence without the concrete expression "This link is dangerous!".  My drafts are as follows:

> 1. If you click ON a dangerous link, a corresponding message will be
>      displayed.
> 2. If you click ON a dangerous link, a message will be displayed as such.
> 3. If you click ON a dangerous link, a message will be displayed
>      accordingly.

Could you advise me on which of these is best.

Comment: *A warning message will be displayed*?

Comment: For me, the concrete expression includes warning.

Comment: Maybe for you... but not for me. I've never seen "warning" implied in this sort of statement.

Comment: Prefer *click ON a dangerous link* to *click a dangerous link*.

Comment: Is this a technical document of some sort? (The word 'drafts' makes me think so.) -- How about this? *If you click a potentially malicious link, the warning message "<put your actual warning message here>" will be displayed.*

Comment: My dictionary has the following example: "The government requires any foods treated by irradiation to be labeled as such."  I would like to describe  my example like this, but I am unsure that "as such" is best for my example.

Comment: @rama9 - "as such" means "in that way" or "as that thing".  So in the example about food irradiation, it means "Foods treated by irradiation must be labeled *as foods treated by irradation*."  That's why *as such* doesn't really make sense in your draft - it isn't clear what "as such" is referring to.

Comment: @stangdon beat me to it.  Your question example isn't quite the same as your food example.  In the question example, the message will be more "as a consequence of" or "relating to" the danger of the link.  You don't really need to make the explicit reference when you immediately follow the mention.  Just describe the nature of the message.  If you insist on something "equivalent to as such": "a related message will be displayed."

Comment: Alternately, you could rephrase the sentence so that "as such" has something to refer to, like "If you click on a link that is dangerous, a message will identify it as such."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, this is the best way I could describe what they mean:

**corresponding**: the message that is displayed is a result of the dangerous link. It is somehow tied/related to the link, but this use of corresponding places *no value* on the content of the message.

**as such**: the message being displayed is somehow telling the reader that the link is dangerous. This sentence sounds the most awkward of the three. "As such" is usually closer in usage to "therefore".

**accordingly**: this is similar to corresponding, but implies more value. It shows that the message will be in agreement with the "value" placed on the dangerous link. That is, that the message will likely give a warning.

For an example to better illustrate the nuance between accordingly and corresponding, consider the following scenario:

Link: **Get free money here**

You click the link, and the corresponding message from the link comes up as "Enter your bank information here to receive your money". However, you have an ad-blocker, and it recognizes the dangerous link and displays the following message accordingly: "Do not trust this link".